# How can I continue to use values from the Entry widget in Tkinter (Python) in a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

I'm learning Python and I'm a beginner. To create a simple program, I use `tkinter`. With the `Entry` widget, I try to input numbers in Python. Then I try to assign that input to a variable.

In the example below, the variable "hoehe" should take the value from the input.

My Python Version: (Python 3.10 (64Bit))

Test Code:

```py
from tkinter import *

import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()  # Phyton Fenster darstellen
root.title("Holzbinder")
root.geometry("200x100")

eingabefeld = Entry(root)
eingabefeld.pack()


def hoehe_ueber_null_greifen():
    global hoehe_ueber_null
    hoehe_ueber_null = eingabefeld.get()
    return hoehe_ueber_null


hoehe = hoehe_ueber_null_greifen()
print(hoehe)

berechnungsknopf = Button(root, text="Berechnen", command=hoehe_ueber_null_greifen)

berechnungsknopf.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: The first time you call `hoehe = hoehe_ueber_null_greifen()` is when the entry was just created so it's obviously empty. When you press the button, `tkinter` calls `hoehe_ueber_null_greifen` so put the `print(hoehe_ueber_null)` at the end of `hoehe_ueber_null_greifen`. I also suggest looking at [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, the variable "height" is obviously empty. However, I don't want to use the function statement "print" but continue to use the function value. If I now set "hoehe = hoehe_ueber_null_greifen()"  under the button, nothing happens either. Sorry If its trivial but I am a beginner :)

Comment: Remove the `hoehe = hoehe_ueber_null_greifen(); print(hoehe)` as they don't do anything useful. Also the `return hoehe_ueber_null` is unneeded. What are you going to do with the user input? Whatever it is, just do it in the function.